# What is an "undirected associative memory" in Hinton et al 2006?

Tags: neural-networks, graphical-model, artificial-intelligence, deep-belief-networks

In [A fast learning algorithm for deep belief nets](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/fastnc.pdf), the authors use the term "undirected associative memory".  I am not sure what they are referring to, and unfortunately Google searches for this term all seem to refer back to this paper.  This leads me to believe the authors are unique in using this terminology and it is probably synonymous with some more commonly used term.  Perhaps in 2006 scholars knew what it was, but I can't be sure.

Is it just a Hopfield Network?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in the context of this paper, it is simply referring to a **Restricted Boltzmann Machine (RBM)**.

(1) A [technical report](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/pointeurs/TR1312.pdf) by Dr. Benjio has a brief summary of the aforementioned paper in section 6.1.  He directly refers to the top layers as an RBM (the original paper called the top layers an "undirected associative memory").

(2) RBMs are sometimes called associative memories, see this [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Restricted-Bolzmann-Machine-called-as-Associative-Memory) for instance.